# javascript which I wrote is wrong(may be)

Tags: javascript

I have tried to write js for my html form. js is working fine with the logically. But if logic fails,I mean if any condition fails it reloads the page,which I don't want. I am providing the code. Please point me out the mistake in js if any.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('submitlink').onclick = function() {

    var bflag = document.addpro.brandflag;
    var brand = document.addpro.brand1.value;
    var cflag = document.addpro.catflag;
    var cat = document.addpro.cat1.value;
    var color1 = document.addpro.color1.value;
    var color2 = document.addpro.color2.value;

    if(cb_validation(bflag,brand))
    {
        if(cb_validation(cflag,cat))
        {
            if(colorcheck(color1,color2))
            {
                document.getElementById('addproform1').submit();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
function cb_validation(flag,field)
{ 
    if(flag[0].checked)
    {
        if(field==0)
        {
            alert('Please Select Both Brand And Category');
            field.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        return true;
    }
    else
    return true;
}
function colorcheck(c1,c2)
{ 
    if((c1==0) && (c2==0))
    {
        alert('Please Select Both Colours');
        document.addpro.color1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if((c1==0))
    {
        alert('Please Select 1st Colour');
        document.addpro.color1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if((c2==0))
    {
        alert('Please Select 2nd Colour');
        document.addpro.color2.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    return true;
}
}
```

I am rookie in js. Please also tell me if I have done any mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return false` is what keeps the page from reloading. Right now it is inside your final color check condition. If you never want the page to reload it needs to be after your first `cb_validation` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Submit() is causing the page refresh which is in below line
document.getElementById('addproform1').submit();

Also both your function is returning true becauseyou are returning true in else block. Hope this points you to right direction....

Good luck....

Comment: The main function does not cancel the click, it only does it for one case, not all the ones that fail. Hence why it always submits/refreshes.